# JavaScript AJAX request function Default parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am just using XML AJAX to get URL to play streaming media whenever button clicked.But In startup Tamil channel list need to display. I need to set default parameter value ex Tamil as default parameter value..

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc('Tamil')">Tamil</button>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc('English')">English</button>

function loadDoc(language) {
  // show the channel list
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Please elaborate more on it.

Comment: Have you tried calling `loadDoc('Tamil')` in your script manually when the page loads?

Comment: @IzumiSy Need to press button to show the list. Default I need to show Tamil list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to load the list on pageload using the value 'Tamil', right?

You could initially load the list by firing the `loadDoc()` function passing 'Tamil' as argument after defining the function when DOM is ready, like so

```
function loadDoc(language) {
    //channel list
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    loadDoc('Tamil');
}, false);
```

If you want to set the default value for `language` you could otherwise do the following

```
function loadDoc(language) {
    if (typeof language == 'undefined) {
        language = 'Tamil';
    }
}
```